# Intellij IDEA can't build simple class

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, java-8

I have Macbook with macOS (latest) running on it. I've installed the latest Intellij IDEA (2020 ultimate) and JDK 8 on it. When I try to compile a simple class it never finishes (build never completes).
I've tried to uninstall and reinstall Intellij IDEA and JDK. No success. I even tried to use different JDK (14) through Intellij IDEA download menu. No success. Any thoughts, ideas, suggestions?

[image: 1]

Comment: Don't use image in question.

Comment: consider reporting to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues as this might require much more details to reproduce it

Comment: Thanks, I've posted there also.

Answer (score 1):

Here what I did. I've installed previous version (2019). And after that I just removed app in Application. I've left all the settings untouched. After that I've installed 2020 and it works just fine :)
Thanks to everyone for giving me directions! Hope it will help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try with antivirus/firewall disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) IDE installation home, IDE executable and project files are excluded from the scan.